# IAccessTokenProvider in Graf (Blazor Web Assembly) MSAL (using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication))

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I want to have access token with Graf in Azure AD Groups, but i became one occure. How i can solve it?

Problem in _graphResourceUrl:  Konvertierung von "string" in "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AccessTokenRequestOptions" nicht möglich.

I will be happy to get any answers!

```
public class CLASS
    {
        private static readonly string _graphResourceUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
        private static string GraphApiBaseUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return $"{_graphResourceUrl}/v1.0";
            }
        }

        private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        private readonly IAccessTokenProvider _accessTokenProvider;

        public GroupsHelper(IAccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider)
        {
            _accessTokenProvider = accessTokenProvider;
        }

        public async Task<List<GraphGroup>> GetGroups(string userId)
        {
        
            var accessToken = await _accessTokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(_graphResourceUrl);
........
}
```